# Rails 3 ActionMailer Model Attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer

I want to form information to my mail after the user filled blanks. But I can't send the user's model attributes to my mail address in HTML format.

```
class DemandMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "mail@mail.com"

  def demand_call(demand)
      mail(:to => "mymail@mail.com" , :subject => "user registered") 
  end
end
```

and the demand_call.html.erb is like that

```
the user name is <%= @demand.name %>
```

but error is

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass):
```

how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should define instance variable inside method

```
  class DemandMailer < ActionMailer::Base
    default from: "mail@mail.com"

    def demand_call(demand)
      @demand = demand
      mail(:to => "mymail@mail.com" , :subject => "user registered") 
    end
  end
```

than can use it inside view

```
the user name is <%= @demand.name %>
```